# String Manipulation with no delimiter

Tags: vb.net, string, reporting-services

I have a string where I need to replace every character in that string with another value. That string has no delimiter. Is it possible to step through that string and replace every value with a set of predetermined values? I would like to keep it to one function as it is going to live within SSRS

```
Dim stringToChange As String = "123456ALWRYA"
```

I would then have to step through the string and replace all off the current values with new ones.

i.e. A=001, B=002, 1=101, 2=102, etc.

Is this possible if the string does not have a delimiter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hum, I'm not a vb.net programmer, but could you please clarify? You want a function that receives a string and replaces each char with another value? Is the target string big enough to hold the new string?

Comment: How about using `String.Replace`? Or loop over each character and add it to a `StringBuilder` and replace if necessary? Have you come up with any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS Custom code has a pretty limited dialect, but this worked for me.

Add the following to the report **Custom Code**:

```
Function SingleReplace (SingleChar As String) As String
  Select Case SingleChar
    Case "A"
      SingleReplace = "001"
    Case "B"
      SingleReplace = "002"
    Case Else
      SingleReplace = SingleChar
  End Select
End Function

Function CustomReplace (BaseString As String) As String

  Dim NewString As New System.Text.StringBuilder

  For Each SingleChar As Char in BaseString
    NewString.Append(SingleReplace(SingleChar))
  Next

  Return NewString.ToString()

End Function
```

Call this in a report expression with:

```
=Code.CustomReplace(Fields!MyString.Value)
```

Works for me in a simple report/table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. I did not know I could step through each line without a delimiter without using some the Regx or something that I know would not be supported through the limits of SSRS's Custom Code.

Comment: I'd use a  `StringBuilder` rather than concatenating every character.

Comment: @Styxxy, fair point. Given the limitations of SSRS Custom Code I just took the simple route, but I've tested and updated the answer with some working code using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Styxxy and Ian Preston, What is the benefit in using StringBuilder as opposed to just calling the 'SingleReplace' Function inside of the 'CustomReplace' Function?

Comment: @Bactos, sorry about the late reply. I think this article has a good summary - it's C# but the same principles apply: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822 So it's more for significant amounts of data, really, so may not even make a difference in your case - I think the point he was making was just to be careful. So I figured I'd test it out and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what Styxxy suggested...with a Dictionary for the looking up the values:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stringToChange As String = "123456ALWRYA"
    Debug.Print(stringToChange)
    Dim changedString = ConvertString(stringToChange)
    Debug.Print(changedString)
End Sub

Private Function ConvertString(ByVal inStr As String) As String
    Static dict As New Dictionary(Of Char, String)
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        dict.Add("A"c, "001")
        dict.Add("B"c, "002")
        dict.Add("1"c, "101")
        dict.Add("2"c, "102")
        ' ... etc ...
    End If

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each c As Char In inStr.ToUpper
        If dict.ContainsKey(c) Then
            sb.Append(dict(c))
        Else
            ' ... possibly throw an exception? ...
            sb.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```